# Getting all invoices with Laravel Cashier

Tags: laravel, payment, gateway

I'm setting up Laravel's Cashier, but I only get the last result when listing all my invoices with

```
Auth::user()->subscription()->invoices();
```

or

```
Auth::user()->invoices();
```

When I'm testing, I'm just making a bunch of payments on the same subscription plan, that is set for a 6 month period. However, since I'm paying multiple times (I have confirmed that in Stripe), shouldn't I be getting all the invoices as well?

Comment: 1.Check your models,hows the relationship is setup? 2.Check directly within database to see if there are multiple rows

Comment: Aren't Stripe's invoices() fetched on-the-fly? I cannot see multiple rows anywhere since they come from Stripe. If I try and count($invoices), the output is always 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an old question - but I ran into the same issue, so posting response.

With Cashier, each subscription is a different instance. The User model only stores the last subscription id.

If you wanted to see multiple invoices for the same subscription, in theory you could set the period to a day, and then wait for a couple of days to see the set of invoices.

Not an issue for testing, but when you create a subscription for a user, you should probably be checking to make sure that there is not one that is active already. Otherwise you are essentially charging the same user multiple times for the same subscription.